# What's the best alternative to Flash for live video from Red5

Tags: flash, video, streaming, live, red5

With Firefox's announcement that they will stop Flash in their browsers, Facebook calling for it's death, and others to potentially follow at some point, what's the best alternative for streaming live video in a browser using Red5?   We use Flash Builder to create a web-based training application that's based around live audio/video.

Answer (score 0):

Without flash the ONLY alternative is Media Source Extensions. This will require fragmented mp4 video. This is commonly (but incorrectly) referred to as DASH.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is still the best available option at this time, even with Firefox enabling the Flash Player as "click-to-play". The currently available options (those with plugins or implementations) are to my knowledge:

- WebRTC
- HLS
- RTSP
- Shoutcast